# Parameter 'i' implicitly has an 'any' type. Ionic2 RC5

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a http call in Ionic2. My code is

```
    getBooksByGnereId(idArray:any){
    console.log(idArray);
    return Observable.forkJoin(
    idArray.map(
        i => this._http.get('http://www.abcd.es/tmdbphp/tmdb_movieby_genre.php?genereid=' + i.id)
            .map(res => res.json())
    ))
  };//
```

Previously my app was working fine, but when I upgraded to **Ionic2 RC5** I am getting error `Parameter 'i' implicitly has an 'any' type`.

If I do i:any, still typescript gives error.

Please help me as I am unable to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. (i:any), while I was doing i:any